# Failed to update packages getting error "gnutls-error #<process elpa.gnu.org> -50" on Windows 10

Tags: microsoft-windows, package-repositories, gnutls

When I run `package-refresh-contents` after running `toggle-debug-on-error` I get the following backtrace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (gnutls-error #<process elpa.gnu.org> -50)
  signal(gnutls-error (#<process elpa.gnu.org> -50))
  package--download-one-archive(("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/") "archive-contents" nil)
  package--download-and-read-archives(nil)
  package-refresh-contents()
  funcall-interactively(package-refresh-contents)
  call-interactively(package-refresh-contents record nil)
  command-execute(package-refresh-contents record)
  execute-extended-command(nil "package-refresh-contents" "package-ref")
  funcall-interactively(execute-extended-command nil "package-refresh-contents" "package-ref")
  call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
  command-execute(execute-extended-command)
```

Taking reference from the discussion found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/c8pm4f/error_when_connecting_to_elpagnuorg/) I tried the following steps:

Running `M-: (gnutls-available-p)` produces:

```
(ClientHello\ Padding Session\ Ticket Extended\ Master\ Secret Encrypt-then-MAC ClientHello\ Padding ALPN Heartbeat SRTP Signature\ Algorithms SRP Supported\ ECC\ Point\ Formats Negotiated\ Groups ...)
```

Running shell command `gnutls-cli -p 443 elpa.gnu.org` from Emacs produces:

```
'gnutls-cli' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Value of the variable `gnutls-trustfiles` is:

```
("/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt" "/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt" "/etc/ssl/ca-bundle.pem" "/usr/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt" "/usr/local/share/certs/ca-root-nss.crt" "/etc/ssl/cert.pem")
```

Added paths of `ssl/cert.pem` and `ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt` in Emacs' installation directory to the `gnutls-trustfiles` variable. In my case they're `c:/Program Files/emacs/ssl/cert.pem` and `c:/Program Files/emacs/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt`. Running `package-refresh-contents` after saving from the variable customization menu and running `eval-buffer` still produces the same error. Restarting Emacs also produces the same error.

> On MS-Windows Emacs is supposed to use the system certificate store through MS-Windows native interfaces. No additional certificates in a separate bundle should be needed. So either your GnuTLS version has a bug of some kind, or your Windows system lacks some updates, or there's a genuine problem with ELPA's certificates.

Emacs version is "GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 1, x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2019-08-29"

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by setting the variable `gnutls-algorithm-priority` to TLS-1.2.

```
(setq gnutls-algorithm-priority "NORMAL:-VERS-TLS1.2").
```

It's because on Windows or Windows Subsystem Linux (WSL) the local gnutls-utils may not support TLS1.3.

Comment: I believe that sets it to allow everything except for TLS 1.2.